# how do I sum pairwise dot products of columns

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I have a dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10, 10))
```

I want to take pairwise dot products of the odd columns with even columns then sum them up.  So column 0 with column 1, column 2 with column 3, and so on.

I've done

```
df.mul(df.shift(axis=1)).sum().sum()
```

But this gets me column 1 and 2, 2 and 3, 3 and 4, which isn't what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
(df.iloc[:, ::2].values * df.iloc[:, 1::2].values).sum()
```

Answer (score 2):

That element-wise multiplication and sum reduction could be thought of as dot product reduction. In this case, we can do it with [`NumPy's tensordot`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.tensordot.html), like so -

```
# Extract the elements as a NumPy array
arr = df.get_values()

# Perform dot product between odd and even columns to get the desired output
out = np.tensordot(arr[:,::2],arr[:,1::2])
```